# chef High CPU Utilization

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Iam quite new to Chef and working on writing a Chef recipe. The goal to identify process that show increasing CPU utilization.

The goal is to find out process that shows increasing CPU utilization and send a mail once it reaches or increases 80%. the check will start from 70 % and once it reaches it needs to send a email giving the details of the PID.

What approach is suitable for this

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Please provide with the ways you are having in mind to approch this, then we can gives you the best hint

Comment: i dont have any thing at this moment . My chef runs for every 30 minutes and so i cannot save the previous run details. I am saving a few details obtained from system into a DB but saving the HIgh CPU usages for every run can cause my DB to load. So iam still trying for ideas

Comment: Why would you use a configuration management system for monitoring ? There's others tools more adapted to the job of monitoring processes cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on your other question, Chef is not a monitoring system, please don't try to use it as one. Chef would be used to deploy and/or configure an actual monitoring system. There are many widely-used monitoring tools out there, though if you want a good one with A+ Chef recipes that already exist, maybe try Sensu. If you want something dirt simple, maybe try Monit.